# Material 3 MaterialSwitch size is too large by default? How to make it smaller?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, material3

I'm using the code below to create a material 3 switch in Android using XML, and it's much larger than a normal switch. Is there any way to make it smaller?

```
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch   
   android:id="@+id/biometrics_switch"   
   style="@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"   
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"   
   app:switchPadding="@dimen/_10sdp" android:minHeight="@dimen/_10sdp" 
   app:thumbTint="@color/white" app:trackTint="@color/neutral_800" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Material Switch width and height affect on clickable area for switch
you should use **scaleX** and **scaleY** to change the size of it.
Also In jetpack compose you should use **Modifier.scale()**

This is a sample code for it:

```
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleX="0.8"
android:scaleY="0.8"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: This behavior of the element sucks, but your answer is right

Comment: This works but then the text size shrinks, as well.